# Как сделать страницу на которую можно будет перейти только по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, php, html, url

Как можно реализовать переход на страницу только по ссылке, а без нее никак?

Comment: а. ссылка полученная через телеграф считается сылкой? лучше напишите от чего Вы хотите защититься..

Comment: А как ещё можно переходить на страницу?

Comment: @vp_arth ну так то можно при посещении одного ресурса поставитть куку, а при посещении закрытого ресурса проверять ее

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, Это всё ещё переход по ссылке, только с учётом не только URI, но и заголовков =) Это обратная задача: "Как сделать, чтобы не каждый мог перейти по ссылке на страницу", проще говоря, авторизация)

Comment: @vp_arth понятно что вопрос задан не верно, но такого рода псевдо защита возможна. вроде однлразовых ссылок

Comment: Думаю ожидался ответ - генерация длинного уникального(трудноподбираемого) ключа, как части ссылки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ||
  trim($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) == "")
    exit();
```

В [php существует предопределённая переменная $_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php), а внутри HTTP_REFERER хранится адрес страницы, с которой был выполнен переход на эту